# where rownum between 500000 and 1000000

Tags: sql, oracle

I've created a table that has 1.8m rows and, while I can extract to CSV, it cannot be opened. This is not a query that is ran often and the end users have very low technical ability. Therefore I wanted a quick and dirty fix that had little time investment.

My solution was to split the query into chunks:

```
SELECT  *
  FROM  my_table 
 WHERE  ROWNUM BETWEEN 0 AND 500000
```

The above works fine however,

```
SELECT  *
  FROM  my_table
 WHERE  ROWNUM BETWEEN 500001 AND 1000000
```

the next iteration does NOT.

I've checked that there are definitely 1.8m rows.

What's going on here? What am I missing?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rownum is applied on query result, not on the table. Apply rownum to get first 1m rows and then filter out the first 0.5m.

```
select *
from (
  SELECT  t.*, rownum rn
  FROM  my_table t
  WHERE  ROWNUM BETWEEN 0 AND 1000000
) where rn > 500000
```

Also, as pointed out by @Connor in comments, rownum filter by itself may not produce deterministic results. Use an `order by` clause to apply appropriate ordering. In that case, the SQL changes to:

```
select *
from (
    SELECT  t.*, rownum rn
    FROM (
        select *
        from my_table
        order by x, y, z -- apply appropriate sort order here
    ) t
    WHERE  ROWNUM BETWEEN 0 AND 1000000
) where rn > 500000
```

This is becomes tedious to write. In Oracle 12c+, the new `FETCH FIRST/NEXT` syntax is much more concise:

```
select *
from my_table
order by x, y, z -- apply appropriate sort order here
offset 500000 rows
fetch next 500000 rows only;
```

Comment: Doh! Of course. As soon as I read your answer I realised. Thanks.

Comment: Just be aware that using *only* rownum, means your result is not deterministic, ie, the very next insert could give you a different result for *existing* rows

Comment: @Connor - Agree. Updated the answer